# Update linked CSV File in Access using C#

Tags: c#, ms-access, linked-tables

I have an MS Access MDB that has a link table from a .csv. I have to change the path so I must use the Linked Table Manager in order to update the path of the csv.

Is any way to do that programmatically using C#?

I have tried to use the help in this link, but it's about Sql and MsAccess.
[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23227079/2486882)

Thank you in advance.

[image]

Comment: Be more specific. Show what you've done . Paste into your question a piece of code .

Answer (score 2):

Say you have an existing linked table named [Foo] that points to the following CSV file:

C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\foo.csv

Access stores the linking information in a TableDef object named "Foo" with the following properties:

```
.Name = "Foo"
.Connect = "Text;DSN=Foo Link Specification;FMT=Delimited;HDR=NO;IMEX=2;CharacterSet=437;ACCDB=YES;DATABASE=C:\Users\Gord\Desktop"
.SourceTableName = "foo.csv"
```

Notice that the `DATABASE=` parameter of the `.Connect` property indicates the *folder* in which the CSV file resides, and the `.SourceTableName` property indicates the *name* of the CSV file.

If you move that file from `C:\Users\Gord\Desktop` to `C:\Users\Public` then all you need to do is update the `DATABASE=` parameter of the `.Connect` property with the new location:

```cs
// required COM reference: Microsoft Office 14.0 Access Database Engine Object Library
//
// using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao; ...
var dbe = new DBEngine();
Database db = dbe.OpenDatabase(@"C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb");
TableDef tbd = db.TableDefs["Foo"];
string oldConnect = tbd.Connect;
char[] delimiter = { ';' };
string[] connectParams = oldConnect.Split(delimiter);
for (int i = 0; i < connectParams.Length; i++)
{
    if (connectParams[i].StartsWith("DATABASE=", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
    {
        connectParams[i] = @"DATABASE=C:\Users\Public";
        break;
    }
}
string newConnect = String.Join(Convert.ToString(delimiter[0]), connectParams);
tbd.Connect = newConnect;
tbd.RefreshLink();
db.Close()
```